# conditional returns (nil) as true

Tags: common-lisp

I started learning common lisp a few days ago so keep in mind i'm a total noob, here's my code:

```
ELISP> (member nil '(2 3 nil))
(nil)

ELISP> (if (member nil '(2 3 nil))
       'true
       'false)
true
```

so my question is how is  "if" returning true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked [the documentation for `member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm):

> If some element *satisfies the test*, the tail of *list* beginning with this element is returned; otherwise [nil](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/a_nil.htm#nil) is returned.

In your case you have a three-element list (the elements being `2`, `3`, and `nil`).

`nil` is a member of this list, so `(member nil '(2 3 nil))` returns a sublist starting at the found element:

```
(nil)  ; a one-element list
```

This value is *true* because only `nil` itself is false; a single-element list containing `nil` is not false.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is correct. `(NIL)` is a list of the length 1, thus a non-empty list, thus treated as `T` when occuring in conditions.

Try this:

```
(if NIL 'true 'false)  ;; false
(if () 'true 'false)    ;; false
(if '() 'true 'false)   ;; false
(if 'NIL 'true 'false)  ;; flase
;; that are all four "identities" of NIL in CL.
;; they are even `eq` to each other, since every lisp has only one 
;; physical address for NIL in their implementation.
;; I imagine it like kind of the root `/` for unix systems ...

;; but (NIL) or ('NIL) or ('()) or (()) are a lists with 1 element in them. thus evaluated to `T`.
(if '(NIL) 'true 'false) ;; true
(if '(()) 'true 'false)  ;; true
(if '('()) 'true 'false) ;; true
(if '('NIL) 'true 'false) ;; true
```

This is like in set theory of mathematics: An empty set has no elements, thus it is empty. But if you put into it the empty set, it is not empty any more, but contains the element 'empty set' as its element.
It can be quite philosophical. Kind of this set contains the idea/representation of an empty set as its element ... and this is not nothing but something.